# How can i start the layout mydialog before starting MainActivity?

Tags: java, android, main-activity

How can start the layout mydialog before starting MainActivity i ve tried a lot of things, none of them worked, could it be possible to start this layout without modifying the launcher in android manifest? thank u in advance for your help.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Dialog mydialog;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mydialog = new Dialog(this);
    Button button =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    Button button2 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    Button button3 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    Button button4=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    Button button5 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    Button button6 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
    Button button7 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
    Button button8 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
    Button button9 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);
    Button button10 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button10);
    Button button11 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button11);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent int1= new Intent(MainActivity.this,buttActivity.class);
            startActivity(int1);
        }
    });
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent int2= new Intent(MainActivity.this,butt2Activity.class);
            startActivity(int2);          }
    });
    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent int3 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, butt3Activity.class);
            startActivity(int3);
        }
    });
    button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent int4 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, butt4Activity.class);
            startActivity(int4);
        }
    });
    button5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent int5 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, butt5Activity.class);
            startActivity(int5);
        }
    });
    button6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent int6 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, butt6Activity.class);
            startActivity(int6);
        }
    });
    button7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent int7 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, butt7Activity.class);
            startActivity(int7);
        }
    });
    button8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent int8 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, butt8Activity.class);
            startActivity(int8);
        }
    });
    button9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent int9 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, butt9Activity.class);
            startActivity(int9);
        }
    });
    button10.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent int10 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, butt10Activity.class);
            startActivity(int10);
        }
    });
    button11.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent int11 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, butt11Activity.class);
            startActivity(int11);
        }
    });



}
public void Showpopup (View v) {
    TextView txtofclose;
    mydialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    txtofclose = (TextView) mydialog.findViewById(R.id.txtofclose);
    txtofclose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mydialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    mydialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    mydialog.show();
}

}
```

Comment: May I ask why your wanting to start happy first?

Comment: Sorry I ment layout

Comment: It s a disclaimer popup, i want it to be at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to accomplish this that I can think of trying without having the ability to tray at the moment.

1. Add a frame layout to main activity indicate the layout
2. Add another activity and have that hold the layout. Then have a shared preferences that hold a flag that you will check if set, if not set on first run. check at app startup if flag is set in shares preferences
3. For out a way to put disclaimer in a dialog box